Does BPTT happen automatically in Torch?
I am looking to implement the algorithms described by the paper Learning Fast Approximations of Sparse Coding by Gregor and LeCun in PyTorch.
My question stems from the algorithm LISTA::bprop.Suppose I write the iterative version of LISTA::fprop : $$\text{for}\ t = 1\ ...\ T:$$
$$Z(k+1) = h_\theta(W_eX + SZ(k)); Z(0) = 0$$
in the forward() method of my nn.The backpropagation step is naturally of the BPTT form. So  my question is that will PyTorch know to conduct BPTT automatically or do I have to code the backprop in too manually?

Questions about specific software are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

So long as your introduced leaf tensors in forward() method support autograd (e.g., via attribute requires_grad=True), PyTorch will automatically handle BPTT via backward() method because it constructs a dynamic computational graph which builds nodes for all relevant tensors defined only from those gradient tracked leaf tensors during the forward pass. See yesterday's related post.
Note in case your $T$ is large, storing intermediate tensors for BPTT can increase memory efficiency. For example, you can use torch.utils.checkpoint to recompute some intermediate states during BPTT to save memory.
